# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 to 11 Beta - Unit Test Project Cannot be Loaded

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We have a Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Framework 4.0 solution, and a C# project in it that contains unit tests.

I uninstalled VS2010 and installed VS11 Beta in a Windows 7 OS. I tried to connect out TFS, did a "get latest" and everything worked fine. Except our unit test project did not open. Its project file checked out automatically but a "load failed" warning is displayed next to the project itself. And under that writes "the project cannot be converted". If you undo checkout, that warning changes to "the project requires user input".

Is there a specific reason or solution for this problem, or is it because VS11 is still in beta?

Thank you.

Here is my csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{7FD06E47-4783-494F-ACB1-256DAB8C0736}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MyProject_TEST</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyProject_TEST</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\$(VisualStudioVersion)\UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>
    <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
    <TestProjectType>WebTest</TestProjectType>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>0</FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>D:\Projects\Work\MyProject\Backup2\</UpgradeBackupLocation>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Enocta_DataLayer, Version=1.0.0.161, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\MyProject_COMMON\assemblies\MyProject_DataLayer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Enocta_Utils, Version=1.0.0.161, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\MyProject_COMMON\assemblies\MyProject_Utils.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Zip, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.XML" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisDependentAssemblyPaths Condition=" '$(VS100COMNTOOLS)' != '' " Include="$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\PrivateAssemblies">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </CodeAnalysisDependentAssemblyPaths>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="[my cs files here].cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject_COMMON\MyProject_Common.csproj">
      <Project>{8EC6C7D7-C89A-4D61-8AE6-32186F3080F1}</Project>
      <Name>MyProject_Common</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject_DBHANDLER\MyProject_DBHandler.csproj">
      <Project>{5C4BBE2F-5C21-4649-B894-B9F7AD3FB619}</Project>
      <Name>MyProject_DBHandler</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject_WebCommon\MyProject_WebCommon.csproj">
      <Project>{549106FD-93DC-4E0B-89BF-1CD41E20762D}</Project>
      <Name>MyProject_WebCommon</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' And '$(IsCodedUITest)' == 'True'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Sharing the project file might be useful. I've upgraded a number of C# unit test projects without a problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing, but with a service project

Answer (score 1):

I've just spend 30 minutes with a similar error - in VS 2011 I had an test project that worked great then I added some web performance test and the project no longer wanted to load "project requires user input" was the error.

I went ahead and started modifying the project file to see what was the problem.
I commented out stuff until the only remaining line was `<Reference Include="System" />` and the project started to load (commented out every file include, every reference add, everything). The end csproj file was similar to a basic WebTest project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>2188741d-638d-4305-b777-db258128221e</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WebAndLoadTestProject2</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WebAndLoadTestProject2</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <TestProjectType>WebTest</TestProjectType>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\$(VisualStudioVersion)\UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>
    <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisDependentAssemblyPaths Condition=" '$(VS100COMNTOOLS)' != '' " Include="$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\PrivateAssemblies">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </CodeAnalysisDependentAssemblyPaths>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' And '$(IsCodedUITest)' == 'True'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Afterwards I started to uncomment my own includes and files - I did it line by line, checking to see if the project is still loadable (trying to catch the culprit).
I did this until the project files was again equal to the original (which did not want to load). Surprisingly, now the project loaded without problems ...

I guess it was something to to with to VS 2011 solution but I have no clue - hopefully in the released version this won't happen.

So go ahead and comment out project specific stuff from your csproj file - test that it loads and then uncomment it and, hopefully, it will work. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem is with the web load tests. Open your project file, (unfortunately) abandon your web load tests, and your test project works successfully.

We had one load test, which was not being used, so this posed no problem. But if this is not the situation for you, this question remains open. I hope this problem is solved in the final release of VS2012.